# Referencing instance variables within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two classes: `TodoList` and `TodoItem`. `TodoList` has an array of `TodoItem`s, and that array is called `todo_items`. Each instance of `TodoItem` has two instance variables: `name` (string) and `complete` (boolean).

I am trying to write a `TodoList` class method to remove a `TodoItem` from this array. The uncommented code below for the `TodoList.remove_item` method works, but it uses `each` to go through the `todo_items` array, checking each `TodoItem` instance's `name`. I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

I was trying to get it to work using `include?` and `delete_at` on `todo_items`, which doesn't work because its contents are class instances of `TodoItem`.

EDIT: Code for both classes `TodoList` and `TodoItem` is below:

TodoList:

```
require "./todo_item"

class TodoList
  attr_reader :name, :todo_items

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @todo_items = []
  end

  def add_item(name)
    todo_items.push(TodoItem.new(name))
  end

  def remove_item(name)
    index = 0
    found = false
    todo_items.each do |todo_item|
      if todo_item.name == name
        found = true
      end
      if found
        break
      else
        index += 1
      end
    end
    if found
      todo_items.delete_at(index)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end #if
  end

#    CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK
#    if (todo_items.include?
#      arr_index = todo_items.(#??)
#      todo_items.delete_at(arr_index) #invalid ref
#      puts "#{name} was removed from the list"
#    else
#      puts "That item does not exist in the to do list."
#    end #if
#  end #def remove_item

end #class TodoList
```

TodoItem:

```
class TodoItem
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @complete = false
  end #initialize

  def to_s
    if complete?
      "[C] #{name}"
    else
      "[I] #{name}"
    end
  end

  def complete?
    @complete
  end

  def mark_complete!
    @complete = true
  end

  def mark_incomplete!
    @complete = false
  end

end #class TodoItem
```

Comment: Why is it a class method? That does not look right.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ```TodoList.remove_item``` is intended to remove a ```TodoItem``` from the ```TodoList.todo_items``` array if the instance variable ```name```'s value matches the argument string. What would you recommend?

Comment: I will add that I am new to Ruby and StackOverflow, clearly, so I appreciate your patience with me. My question is, is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do (see above) with the class method?

Comment: Are you sure `remove_item` and `todo_items` work on the class `TodoList` and not its instance?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking. I edited my original post to include the full code for both classes.

Comment: You have neither `TodoList.remove_item` nor `TodoList.todo_items`. In your code, `remove_item` and `todo_items` are instance methods.

Comment: You... are right. Thank you. That comment you edited out about being tired may have been more relevant than you thought. :)

Comment: I have two suggestions. First, a small one: in `TodoList#add_item` and `TodoList#remove_item`, change `name` to `item_name` to avoid confusion with the list name. More substantive, make `@todo_items` a hash rather than array. In `Totdo#add_item(item_name)`, for example, you'd have `@todo_items[item_name] =  TodoItem.new(item_name)`. That would avoid the need for finding instances of items you wish to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)** like:

```
def remove_item(name)
  todo_items.delete_if { |x| x.name == name}
end
```

And if you still want boolean to be returned, then

```
def remove_item(name)
  found = todo_items.index { |x| x.name == name }  # return nil if not found or the index.
  todo_items.delete_if { |x| x.name == name}
  !!found # turn to boolean
end
```

*PS:* `remove_item` should be an instance method of class `TodoList`.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, except I'm unsure what ```x``` would be in this instance, in reference to an instance of ```TodoItem```. For example, if I use my ```TodoList.add_item``` class method, it generates a new instance of ```TodoItem``` and sets the variable ```name``` to its single argument. How would I reference that item as ```x```?

Comment: It's up next in my Treehouse track! Maybe I'll continue on and come back to this, if that will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_item(name)
  !!todo_items.reject!{|e| e.name == name}
end
```